# How to find week of the year for the date value?

Tags: apache-nifi

My Flow having attribute '05-05-2015'.And i need to find week of the date in NiFi.

```
For example:

if date is 05 then it is belongs to 1st week of the year.
```

I shouldn't use Script/Program for find out week.

i need to find out that using NiFi Expression language only.

Can anyone suggest way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assume `eee` is your attribute

then expression

```
${eee:toDate('MM-dd-yyyy'):format('u E')}
```

output:
`2 Tue`

format reference:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html